Consecutive appearance of heads or tails on coin flip
When a coin is tossed a large number of times $N$, about half of all  tosses  would be either heads or tails.
What is the expected number of two (or three or four) heads   $ (p_2,p_3,p_4)$ occurring together or consecutively ?
What is $p_n$ as a function of $n$ for large $N$? The function is expected to reduce fast with $n$.

If the coin tosses are supposed to continue forever (due to the very large value of $N$), all possible combinations of heads and tails are virtually guaranteed to occur. Consider $p_3$ for instance, if you keep tossing a coin for a long time (again, due to very large $N$), it is almost certain that you’d get 3 heads in a row at some point. IMHO, your question might be better formulated as $p_{n,N}$

Also see this post, which talks about $p_{n,N}$

To me, the question is poorly worded/unclear (Please clarify the question).

Am new to this. I wanted to ask for large  N say 1 million toss results lined up then  what is the probability of finding the number of  pure doublets, pure triplets and  pure quadruplets and  pure polyplets $n<N$ in that line. Please help suggest how it may be written out in a better way.

That doesn't make sense. Do you mean that you want to find the expected number of pure doubles, pure triplets, etc.?

What is a "pure" doublet?

@AdamRubinson: Yes, that is what I meant. I.e., in $TTTHT  HHHTTHTTTHTHT$ there are three triples or three pure triplets

Pure=not part of a longer contiguous sequence, right?

And in the sequence you’ve shown, you are considering both tails and heads, but in the question you mention only consecutive heads?

Yes, exactly so.

Thanks. Out of three Heads&Tails triples there are two Heads triples which are selected for probability count and one Tails triple that is deselected. Is it better?

I see only one sequence of three consecutive heads in TTTHTHHHTTHTTTHTHT.

Also the number of "pure singleton" heads will usually be much less than $N/2$. When we say about half of the tosses will be heads we are not talking about "pure" heads.

This is kind of an interesting combinatorics question.  You can find the exact value as a sum of many terms, but this may be unrealistic if $N$ is large. There is probably a better way to find a theoretical estimate. But the easiest way to estimate
would be using simulations.

Use linearity of expectation. For every consecutive pair find the probability that it can be qualified as (what you call) a "pure" Heads doublet. Then take their summation. Similar for triples, et cetera.

$\def\ed{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}$
Let
\begin{align}
I_{nt}&\ed\cases{1&if $\ t=0\ $ and the first $\ n\ $ tosses are all heads.\\
1&if $\ t\ge1\ $, the $\ t^\text{th}\ $ toss is a tail, and it's\\
&followed by a run of $\ n\ $ $\it{or\ more}$ heads.\\
0&otherwise,}\\
H_n^+&\ed\text{number of runs of $\ n\ $ or more heads, and}\\
H_n&\ed\text{number of runs of}\ {\it exactly}\ n\ \text{heads}\ .
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\big(I_{nt}\big)&=\mathbb{P}\big(I_{nt}=1\big)\\
&=\cases{\frac{1}{2^n}&if $\ t=0 $ and $\ N\ge n\ .$\\
\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}& if $\ 1 \le t\le N-n\ $\\
0&otherwise}\\
H_n&=\cases{I_{n0}&if $\ n=N$\\
H_n^+-H_{n+1}^+&if $\ n<N$}\\
&=\sum_{t=0}^N\big(I_{nt}-I_{n+1\,t}\big)\ \ \text{ if }\ n<N.
\end{align}
Therefore, if $\ n=N\ ,$ then
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\big(H_n\big)&=\mathbb{E}\big(I_{n0}\big)\\
&=\frac{1}{2^n}\ ,
\end{align}
and if $\ 1\le n<N\ ,$ then
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\big(H_n\big)&=\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{t=0}^
N\big(I_{nt}-I_{n+1\,t}\big)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2^n}+\sum_{t=1}^{N-n}\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}-\sum_{t=1}^{N-n-1}\frac{1}{2^{n+2}}\\
&=\frac{N+2-n}{2^{n+1}}-\frac{N-n+1}{2^{n+2}}\\
&=\frac{N-n+3}{2^{n+2}}\ ,\text{ and}\\
\frac{\mathbb{E}\big(H_n\big)}{N}&=\frac{1}{2^{n+2}}\left(1-\frac{n-3}{N}\right)\ .
\end{align}
